# Decoding with Opus API using opus_decode_float

Tags: c, opus

I'm trying to use the basic encoding and decoding functions of the OPUS api with this main :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opus/opus.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  OpusEncoder   *enc;
  OpusDecoder   *dec;
  unsigned char         *str;
  float         frame = 0.32;
  int           ret = 0;
  int           error;
  float         *returned;

  if ((str = malloc(4096)) == NULL)
    return (-1);
  enc = opus_encoder_create (24000, 1, OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO, &error);

  printf("ret = %d | input = %.2f\n", error, frame);

  ret = opus_encode_float(enc, &frame, 480, str, 4096);

  printf("ret = %d\n", ret);

  dec = opus_decoder_create (24000, 1, &error);
  ret = opus_decode_float(dec, str, ret, returned, 480, 0);

  printf("ret = %d | res = %.2f\n", ret, returned[0]);

  return (0);
}
```

The trouble is that I'm trying to pass the 0.32 float in encoding and decode it with opus_decoder_float, but when I'm trying to print my result I only get 0.00 and I can't find any example of usage with this specific function.

I don't get any error message with the ret value, the program prints :

```
ret = 0 | input = 0.32
ret = 3
ret = 480 | res = 0.00
```

How can I get the 0.32 in the returned float ?

Comment: Suggest checking the return value like `enc` and `dec`.

Answer (score 0):

`returned` not initialized.  `opus_decode_float()` and `printf()` receives a pointer with an indeterminate value.

```
  // problem code
  returned  float         *returned;  
  ...
  // What value is `returned`?
  ret = opus_decode_float(dec, str, ret, returned, 480, 0);
  printf("ret = %d | res = %.2f\n", ret, returned[0]);
```

Suggested fix, allocate memory.  [opus_decode_float()](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus/ws/doc/html/group__opus__decoder.html#ga9c554b8c0214e24733a299fe53bb3bd2)

```
  returned  float         *returned;
  ...
  int frame_size = 480;
  int channels = 1;  // from `opus_encoder_create (24000, 1, ...`

  returned = malloc(sizeof *returned * frame_size * channels);
  assert(returned);
  ret = opus_decode_float(dec, str, ret, returned, frame_size, 0);

  printf("ret = %d | res = %.2f\n", ret, returned[0]);
  free(returned);
```

---

Further, As I read the [doc](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus/ws/doc/html/group__opus__encoder.html#ga4ae9905859cd241ef4bb5c59cd5e5309), `pcm` below needs a pointer to a large array of `float` (frame_size*channels), not just 1.

```
opus_int32 opus_encode_float(OpusEncoder *st, const float *pcm,
    int frame_size, unsigned char *data, opus_int32 max_data_bytes) 

// Too small?
float frame = 0.32;
ret = opus_encode_float(enc, &frame, 480, str, 4096);
```

Comment: That could have been the trouble, though even when I allocate the float as said I still get 0.00 in the end.

Comment: @S.Hochberg Note: Code has many _magic numbers_ like 4096, 24000, 1 without a self-evidence meaning - this adds to difficulty in understanding the code.  Example: Better to use something like `int frame_size = 480;` and then `frame_size` than `480` in various places to clearly convey the object's meaning.  AFAIK the 4096 is wrong.  Why 4096?

Comment: Well they needed a size for the buffer so for test purposes I didn't thought this very much and just set it to 4096. 24000 and 1 are numbers asked by the Opus API corresponding to the sampling rate of input signal and the number of channels (1 corresponds to mono and 2 stereo)

Comment: @S.Hochberg I know what the values are for and how they are needed, _after_ looking them up - but that took time.  As said, making code self-evident, self-documenting aids in better understanding for reviewers in focusing on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Opus has 2.5 to 6.5 ms of lookahead, depending on encoder parameters.  Therefore the output of decoding will be slightly delayed compared to the input, and for sample-accurate decoding you should skip those initial samples from the decoder and decode the same number of extra samples at the end.  The exact number of samples of lookahead can be obtained using:

```
opus_int32 skip;
opus_encoder_ctl(enc, OPUS_GET_LOOKAHEAD(&skip));
```

That means that you should skip the first `skip` decoded samples to get the sample that corresponds to the first sample of input.

Also keep in mind that it is lossy compression.  While it is intended to sound the same as the original to a human listener, you shouldn't expect the values of the samples to be the same.